# Inferior Python Shell - Windows - not printing results

Tags: python, spacemacs, microsoft-windows, ipython

I'm trying to use inferior python shell to run ipython commands interactively. I am able to connect but it doesn't print the results of my statements except when I use print statements

```
In [1]: a = 10

In [5]: a

In [6]: a.real

In [12]: print "hello"
hello
```

I am using the latest version of spacemacs with the Python layer and the following user configuration settings:

```
(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python.exe"
    python-shell-interpreter-args
    "-i c:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\Scripts\\ipython-script.py")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (with Ipython 7.13.0), and found no solution. Can anyone tell if there is a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem seems to be on the iPython side.
Upgrading to 5.1.0 fixed the problem, both with Anaconda iPython or MSYS2 iPython.